# C++ Strings in Xcode

Tags: c++, string, xcode

I am currently writing a C++ program on Xcode. The following is a snippet of the code I am running:

```
char myString[3];
cin >> myString;
cout << myString << endl;
```

The code is very straightforward. However, when I enter strings longer than 2 characters, the string still accepts them. Why doesn't the string only store two characters plus the null terminator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it can't. When you pass an array into a function (`operator>>` counts!) by value, you're really just passing a pointer to the array. A `char*` doesn't know the size of the buffer it points to.

In theory the standard library could have been designed so that it had a function template taking a reference to the array, like:

```
template <size_t N>
operator>>(char (&input)[N]);
```

But, well, it just doesn't. You could propose its addition to the C++ standards committee.

Anyway, there's no need for formatted extraction here. Prefer something like:

```
cin.read(&myString[0], sizeof(myString)-1);
```

…or use an actual string.

Comment: @xskxzr: Heh... habit.

Comment: Nearly all of my "dang, nearly" compilation errors after coding for a while, are when I sprinkled `const` where I shouldn't've.